# Json.net configure a node to be implicit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, json, json.net

Im not sure this can be done, basically I'm struggling to map c# objects to a json feed.

the problem is the json text contains a object name that is actually a unique id meaning I cant simply use a single object for the mapping.

```
{
    "Persons": {
        "12345": {
            "surname": "smith", 
            "firstname":  "jim"
            "language": "en"
        },
       "99999": {
            "surname": "blog", 
            "firstname":  "joe"
            "language": "en"
        },
        "87534": {
            "surname": "bond", 
            "firstname":  "james"
            "language": "en"
        }
    }
}
```

the object structure I have is a class called Persons containing a IList property.

As you can see the object names are actually unique id's, but could be the same type.
I dont have control over the json feed so I cant simply edit that end.

Is there anything I can do to fix this in json.net? maybe a attribute???

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you're using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`? Is manually creating the JSON okay for you?

Comment: This looks an awful lot more like a `Dictionary` than a `List`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a JSON.NET user so I apologize if this doesn't apply. Your JSON structure appears that it would better match a `Dictionary<int, Person>` collection where `Person` is defined:

```
public class Person
{
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
}
```

Hierarchical data structures typically don't mesh well with `List<T>` collections.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered JSON.NET myself, so not sure if what I say is 100% accurate.  I don't think you can use serialization because as you pointed out, the input string is not a proper JSON, so serialization code will most likely choke on that.

So what you want to do is do some preprocessing and get that list into a proper form before doing further work on it.  Seems LINQ to JSON is a perfect solution for this since LINQ allows you to manipulate individual elements as needed.  So you can take a property name, and recreate new object type which contains "id" whose value happens to match what outside property name used to be.

I think this is what you want:

```
    private void Test1()
    {
        string testInput = @"{
                                ""Persons"": {
                                    ""12345"": {
                                        ""surname"": ""smith"", 
                                        ""firstname"":  ""jim"",
                                        ""language"": ""en""
                                    },
                                    ""99999"": {
                                        ""surname"": ""blog"", 
                                        ""firstname"":  ""joe"",
                                        ""language"": ""en""
                                    },
                                    ""87534"": {
                                        ""surname"": ""bond"", 
                                        ""firstname"":  ""james"",
                                        ""language"": ""en""
                                    }
                                }
                            }";

        JObject jsonPeople = JObject.Parse( testInput );

        var query = from p in jsonPeople[ "Persons" ].Children().Cast< JProperty >()
                    select new JObject( 
                        new object[] { new JProperty( "id", p.Name ) }
                        .Concat( p.Value.Children() ) );

        JObject outJson = new JObject( new JProperty( "Persons", query ) );

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print( outJson.ToString() );
    }
```